# Workflow orchestration using Google Cloud Platform in SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to develop a workflow in Google Cloud Platform (similar to Microsoft Azure Logic Apps) with SharePoint Online.

The requirement is that when an incoming email arrives on the user account Outlook mailbox, I can save the email metadata in a SharePoint List. This I have already achieved in Azure Logic Apps because of actions / triggers available in Logic Apps. However as the client is having GCP platform, the same needs to be implemented on GCP.

I explored Cloud Composer in Google Cloud Platform (GCP), however not sure if the functionality mentioned above can be achieved using GCP.

Comment: You could achieve this in Azure because you have Logic Apps with outlook connector. So you have a trigger for your workflow. As far as I know there is no such connector in GCP. But if you can manage to have such a trigger you can use a combination of Cloud PubSub and Cloud Function with proper authentication / authorisation to manage to implement such workflow (using code not UI components)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share a high-level working example or steps which would guide me as a starting point (kindly note I am new to GCP and have good experience in Azure). As far as I know, Cloud PubSub is a Messaging Queue Service in GCP.